# Is it possible to limit the level at which entries can be selected from within an entries field?

Tags: relations, structure, entries-field

I have an entires field which is using a structure as a source. 
The structure has 3 levels and I would like to be able to limit it so the user can only select entries at the second level.

I've had a look through the docs and at the field settings but it doesn't seem to be doable. If anyone knows a work around or a plugin which can do this that would be great. I wonder if it is possible to create a plugin to extend this field to do this if not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a popular feature request for this:
["Entry Type" setting for Entries fields](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7179163--entry-type-setting-for-entries-fields)

But yes, it's currently also possible to do this by extending the default entries field type
and adding your custom criteria with `getInputSelectionCriteria()`.

```
class BusinessLogic_CustomEntriesFieldType extends EntriesFieldType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Entries (custom)');
    }

    protected function getInputSelectionCriteria()
    {
        return array(
            'level' => 2
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have up voted that feature. I'll have a look at extending that field.

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat! I'm going to add an additional input so you can specify the level.